# GTA V Online Character Transfer PS3 to PS4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I recently just bought a PS4 that I couldn't pass up (Price Wise) and decided to try and transfer my GTA V Online Character.

Stats:
All stat bars full
$204,000,000
Rank: 149

I've been playing the game since it came out, which was around 2013 I believe. I quit playing the game about 8 months ago because my hard drive in my PS3 died on me so I decided to put the console on the shelf for a while. Like stated above, I just bought me a new PS4 and was looking to try and transfer my character over. I tried calling Rockstar Support about my situation and all they told me was that they don't allow transfers anymore.

So here's my question... Is there absolutely any way that I can transfer my character to my next gen console?

Comment: Support just said they can't do anything; what makes you think we can?

Answer (score 6):

It is no longer possible to transfer characters in GTA V.

As of March 6th, 2017 [character transfers have been discontinued](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115010081668-Character-Transfer).

A [Rockstar article](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007553888) also states:

> Question: Can I transfer my character from my current platform to another?
>
> Answer: No, this is not possible.  There is currently no feature available to transfer character data between platforms.

There are no legal ways to transfer a character in GTA V anymore. Since the data for characters is online based, you'd be hard pressed trying to transfer a character by different means, if it's even possible. Support also states that if you attempt to transfer a character, nothing will happen.